# TouchID : How to get touch id authentication attempts?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to implement touch ID and have to show alert to user for authentication attempts left. Below code Im using.

reply block not getting called after one wrong authentication attempt. Its getting called after 3 continues wrong authentication attempt. Is there any way to get count of wrong authentication attempts..?

```
LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];

NSError *authError = nil;
NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Touch ID Test to show Touch ID working in a custom app";

if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
              localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                            if (success) {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Success" sender:nil];
                                });
                            } else {
                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                        message:error.description
                                                                                       delegate:self
                                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                                    [alertView show];
                                    NSLog(@"Switch to fall back authentication - ie, display a keypad or password entry box");
                                });
                            }
                        }];
} else {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:authError.description
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I went through the documentation, it is not possible to show alert in each failed attempt. Just refer the documentation
[LocalAuthentication in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication). 
 
You can show alerts at different error cases. After 3rd failed attempt **LAError.authenticationFailed** will be called and after 5th failed attempt **LAError.touchIDLockout** will be called. You can display the alerts here. For more info refer [Apple LAError documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/laerror)